# Couchbase N1QL value Decode function

Tags: couchbase, sql++

Is there an equivalent of the Oracle SQL `DECODE` function in N1QL?

I.e. a function which allows you to choose to output one or other value, based on a conditional check:

`select sum(decode(type = 'car', 1, 0)) carCount from mybucket`

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DECODE will be available in next release. In mean time you can use CASE expression

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'car' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) carCount 
FROM mybucket;
```